# Firebase Realtime Database Emulator: Can't read from database (snapshot is always null) even though onWrite function gets triggered

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have a very simple Cloud Function running in the emulator:

```
functions.region('europe-west1').database.ref('teams/{teamId}/members/{memberId}')
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('teams').once('value')
    console.log(26, snapshot.exists())
    console.log(snapshot.val())
})
```

When I change a member or add a new member in the emulator this function gets triggered (so 'teams' is 100% defined) however the snapshot is always empty and does not exist.

I am staring the emulator with the following command :

```
firebase emulators:start --import ./folder
```

The folder has a JSON file with my database.
Anyone has any idea what is causing this? So frustrating, literally always see null in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two different database instances in different regions. The emulator was listening for changes in database A but reading in database B. I had only emulated database A.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the function in order to run it in the local Firebase emulator. You may also refer to these [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec) on how Execution Environment works.

I have reproduced the error from your given code. Below is working sample function based on your given code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var functions = require("firebase-functions")
 
// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
admin.initializeApp();
 
// As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
 
exports.simpleDbFunction = functions.region('europe-west1').database.ref('teams/{teamId}/members/{memberId}')
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('teams').once('value')
    console.log(26, snapshot.exists())
    console.log(snapshot.val())
})
```